# How to reference the WebContext.Current.User from a separate controls project?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a [appname].[ui] project that exists separate from my main silverlight 4 application. I do need to be able to bind to the WebContext.Current.User object in one of those controls and I don't know how to get an instance of it since it is in the Generated_Code hidden folder in the [application].web.g.cs file.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a RIA Services Class Library project containing the WebContext class.
Other client side projects can reference that class library project.
for instructions on how to structure your solution, you can refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707351%28v=VS.91%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of doing something along the lines but that would require too much change across many application. My UI project is supposed to be shared between multiple silverlight apps, and each of them is married so to speak to their [application].Web project. Though I know I can separate the two, and have the WebContext exists in its own library, that would cause way too much code changes. As of now I am telling everyone to just copy the controls in question as I will no longer be developing them in a separate project.